# Iphone multi screen/view application

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa

I am very new to iPhone development, i am developing one sample application using xcode.
I am referring on-line tutorials and examples to build my first application.

I want to try multi screen/view application where i want to display specific screens on some specific events like button clicks.

I googled for tutorials on multi screen iPhone apps, but i am getting different ways of doing it.

I am confused in-between:
1. Navigation based application.
2. Window based application.
3. View based application.

Which application type do i need to chose for multi view/screen application. Is it that we can't create multi view/screen application using 2nd and 3rd type, i think this should not be the case, but i am confused.

what i have done so far.

I have created one window based application where i have one login page (text fields and click buttons) i want to extend this application to display main screen/error screen based on the login result.

I have created 2 `.xib` files for main screen and error screen(with there corresponding .m and .h controller files), now i want to remove login screen and display main screen/error screen, but i don't have idea how to archive this when we are in window based application.

can some one point to useful tutorials/examples that can explain this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before getting into any online tutorials it'd be better to go through apple's guides.
Following guides could be a good start:

[App Programming Guide - Design Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppDesignBasics/AppDesignBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1) To understand the basics of iOS development

[Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556)

and

[View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html)

To understand and implement different view controllers

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps your question regarding delegation
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-iphone-application-with-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards with scenes and segues (iOS 5+), this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboarding_%28iPhone_iOS_5%29) might help clear things out.